# php if statement null and 0?

Tags: php

i'm having trouble executing my if statement

> if($parent == $page->parent)

my dollar $parent = null and my $page->parent = 0 how do i fix this that they are equal?

i think it's a problem with the fact it doesn't know that null is equal to 0

```
$page = Page::find($id);
$parent = Input::get('parent'); // Null
```

i hope you guys can help me out i have to figure this out

here's my controller just in case you wan't to take a look at it

```
public function updateMenu($id)
{
    $page = Page::find($id);
    $parent = Input::get('parent');
    $new_order = Input::get('index');

    if($parent == $page->parent)
    {
        if($page->order_id > $new_order)
        {
            DB::table('pages')
                ->where('parent',$parent)
                ->where('order_id', '<', $page->order_id)
                ->increment('order_id');
        }
        else
        {
            DB::table('pages')
                ->where('parent',$parent)
                ->where('order_id', '>=', $page->order_id)
                ->decrement('order_id');
        }
    }
    else
    {

            DB::table('pages')
                ->where('parent',$parent)
                ->where('order_id', '>=', $new_order)
                ->increment('order_id');

    }



    $page->order_id = Input::get('index');
    $page->parent = Input::get('parent');

    $page->save();

    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Well `null == 0` evaluates to `true` and `null === 0` evaluates to `false`, but I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Please provide a `var_dump` of both variables.

Comment: if i var_dump nothing happens

Comment: but my variables work because they do store in my database

Answer (score 1):

I dont think **0** can be equals with **NULL**. maybe `if($parent == $page->parent || ($parent == null && $page->parent == 0))` more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use the strict equality operator: === instead of ==

```
localhost> = 0 === null
false
localhost> = 0 == null
true
```

Comment: I will upvote because, you wrote what I was going to write and there is a 'wink' in your lastname.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(is_null($parent) && ($page->parent==0))
{

}
```